# Apache cordova how to generate release apk

Tags: release

Before i start, i will warn you guys that im not an app developer and that i did not code this app, and that i have no expirience with apache cordova.

So i'm using apache cordova in visual studio 2013 and i'm here trying to get the release .apk but when i try to run a release build on a device i get the following error.

"Android packages must be signed when debugging using the Release or Distribution configurations." I've been googling solutions to this but i could not find any, though i did find that i need to change several things to get the .apk file i want.

So the first step would be making a keystore for the app right? Well, i have no clue on how to do this, and all the answers i found where using the cordova cli which i don't even know how to open. Can anyone tell me what a keystore is and how do i get it. If i need to use the cordova cli how do i open it.
After this, what should i do?

Comment: Seems that you have to follow these instructions:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx

for generate a keystore, i use android studio that has a wizard.
I don't know if Visual Studio permits to generate and sign a key store, if not you can sign via other tool like Android Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: Those steps did not help unfortunately.
And where should i put the keystore ?

Comment: i never used visual studio, i'm sorry. Within Eclipse, when you export the project automatically generate a key. I suggest to install eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to resolve this problem. will get back to you soon.